# Scale every object on all keyframes at once

Tags: animation, transforms

I have more around 300 objects in the scene, every object has its animations baked from frame 1 to frame 1000, and I have to scale every object up. Is there any way to do this without having to do it for the 1000 keyframes one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Set an empty parent of all 300 objects and scale the empty.